# is it possible to make reusable code for adding background image? If so, how?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm working on Swift and I wonder how to add the same background image into different view controllers programmatically.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    setBackground()
}


func setBackground() {
    view.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
    backgroundImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    backgroundImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    backgroundImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    backgroundImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    backgroundImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    
    backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: K.imageForFirstScreen)
    view.sendSubviewToBack(backgroundImageView)
}
```

for now, I make setBackground() function in each view controllers since I want to display the same background image onto multiple view controllers and call the function in viewDidload every time. So, I wanted to know if there is a way to declare setBackground function somewhere and I can just call the function in viewDidLoad. I know I can set a background image in the attribute inspector, but I want to know how I can write in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many methods you could use. One would be to put the method in `UIViewController` extension and call it in the `UIViewController` sub-classes you want to add it.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func setBackground() {
        //...
    }
}
```

Then:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    setBackground()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 extension UIViewController {
     func setBackground(color: UIColor?) {
        self.view.backgroundColor = color
     }
 }
```

How to use: Now you will have this function in each subclass of UIViewController

```
class MyNewClass: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setBackground(color: UIColor.red)
    }

}
```